# Как возвести целое число в степень 2 без использования ** и pow?

Tags: python

Дано целое число n и нужно возвести его в степень 2ки, т е n = 10 и вывод 1024.

Как это вообще монжо сделать без использования ** и pow?

Comment: Ну например напишите цикл ..

Comment: Это я понял, просто я пробовал все время и у меня кроме умножения ничего не получается(

Comment: Задача не поставлена правильно. В заголовке и тексте говорится о возведении числа в степень (какую?) двойки, а пример для возведения двойки в степень заданного числа. Приведите задание точно, а не в перепеве Р.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Многократное умножение подойдёт, если я правильно понял...

```
ans = 1
num = 2
n = int(input())

for _ in range(n):
    ans *= num
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: То есть как? ***

Comment: Добавил код, двойку можно тоже при желании вводить с клавиатуры

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться оператором побитового сдвига [Побитовые операторы(bitwise) в Python](https://pythonim.ru/osnovy/pobitovye-operatory-bitwise-v-python).

```
n = 10
print('Результат: ', 1 << n)
print('Проверка: ', 2 ** n)
```

```
Результат:  1024
Проверка:  1024
```

Comment: Только это не возведение числа в степень двойки, а умножение числа на степень двойки